# How to get results of split test programmatically?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

In Facebook Marketing API there are Split Testing. This is Ad Study which should be created without "objectives". But the problem is I don't know how to get the results of the split test?

In documentation, I found one paragraph that described how to get results of Conversion Measurement study (another kind of ad study, with objectives). For this, I should get Objectives first which not exists in Split Tests.

Any suggestions?